# Recursive looping through xts

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I'm modelling the development of the orderbook over time. I have an initial orderbook shape in xts and then the subsequent depth updates also in xts:

The initial orderbook shape looks as follows (all entries have the same time):

```
                            BID.price       size
2014-02-11 23:59:42.494426  508.1000        10.0000000
2014-02-11 23:59:42.494426  509.1200         8.0000000
2014-02-11 23:59:42.494426  509.1000        10.0000000
```

and the subsequent depth udpates look as follows:

```
                           BID. price       size
2014-02-12 04:57:51.191514 508.1000        -10.00000000
2014-02-12 04:57:51.640302 514.0000         10.00000000
```

What I need to to is:

1) for each row in updates, compare the price with the orderbook:

1a) If the updates price level is in orderbook already, adjust the size accordingly, so the example above would look as follows:

```
                            BID.price       size
2014-02-12 04:57:51.191514  509.1200         8.0000000
2014-02-12 04:57:51.291514  509.1000        10.0000000
```

(the price level 508.10000 was deleted, and time was updated)

1b) If the depth updates is not in orderbook yet, add new prise level with given size, so the example would looks like:

```
                            BID.price       size
2014-02-12 04:57:51.640302  509.1200         8.0000000
2014-02-12 04:57:51.640302  509.1000         10.0000000
2014-02-12 04:57:51.640302  514.0000         10.00000000
```

(new price level of 514 was added and time was adjusted).

Is there any convenient and fast way how to do such thing avoiding the for loop over depth updates xts?

Thanks!

Comment: 1- I don't think you can avoid the for loop here. Anyway , try to add what you have tried and also put your data in a readable format( hard to use at is now).

Comment: @agstudy: ok, and jsut to clarify, what do you mean by readable format? Pasted data comes directly from R.

Comment: You should use `dput(head(your_data)`, and also do you really have an xts object? I mean do you need a time series here , look that you just need the last day, Maybe a simple data.frame(bid,size) is sufficient.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not clear. Are you trying to build a time series of the orderbook state, or are you just trying to update a snapshot of the orderbook?

Comment: I'm sorry for a vague description. What I need to have is a time serie reflecting a state of an orderbook at time when any orderbook update occured.

Comment: Then I would encourage you to reconsider your data structure. It would probably be easier to work with an xts object with 1 row for each timestamp, and a column for each bid/ask price and size for however many levels you want to store (e.g. 10 levels = 40 columns).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich wide format is a good idea if OP only have a fix column(variable) number. Do you assume that he will check  a limited number of bi/ask each time?

Comment: @agstudy: Yes, I assume they want to track a certain number of bids/asks. But it's hard to know what to recommend with such limited information. They don't even say what market this data comes from, and each market's order book is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think no need to use an xts object here since the index is the same for all observations and the right id here is the bid variable. So I explain my solution using 1 simple data.frame as shown above:

```
DT                  ## the day before
  day    bid size
1   1 508.10   10
2   1 509.12    8
3   1 509.10   10
DT1                ## the current or last day
  day   bid size
1   2 508.1  -10
2   2 514.0   10
```

Now using `merge` we have nearly the solution:

```
dtm
     bid day.x size.x day.y size.y
1 508.10     1     10     2    -10
2 509.10     1     10    NA     NA
3 509.12     1      8    NA     NA
4 514.00    NA     NA     2     10
```

Now we should just adjust size and remove bids with a null positions. I cerate here an intermediate %+% function to deal with missing values.

```
## compute size
"%+%" <- function(x,y) 
     ifelse(is.na(x),
            ifelse(is.na(y),NA,y),
            ifelse(is.na(y),x,NA))
## remove  numm poistion(size==0)
subset(transform(dtm,size=size.x%+%size.y,day=max(day.y,na.rm=T)),
       size !=0,select=c(day,bid,size))

 day    bid size
2   2 509.10   10
3   2 509.12    8
4   2 514.00   10
```

I think you can get more succicent and syntax sugar solution here using `data.table`.

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion! I will try it and let you know. I still need to have the results as xts but I guess I can do it at the very end.

Comment: @SteefGregor technically yes, you can store all your snapshot in a time series.

Comment: Your solution worked well, thanks! And as you suggested in the comment above, I cannot use the one line representation as the length of a vector is conctantly changing.